# Embedding Font in IE does not work

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am trying to embed a font in Internet Explorer, but it does not seem to work. I have already searched the forum here, but nothing that I read here worked.

My code is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"UniversLTW01-57Condense_723821";
    src:url("Fonts/723821/aefefc4e-9cb8-4e8e-8599-dda705456734.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* For IE */
        url("Fonts/723821/87512e82-56b3-4356-97ab-9cd7b2957e37.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("Fonts/723821/1eaf27c0-f4de-4273-9f4c-1b3236ad2f3c.woff") format("woff"),
        url("Fonts/723821/9b913baf-b1f0-47d2-8c76-42f59650058f.ttf") format("truetype"),
        url("Fonts/723821/0abcce12-2274-4ee7-b6d5-0066b5f5f670.svg#0abcce12-2274-4ee7-b6d5-0066b5f5f670") format("svg");
}
```

Instead of `format("embedded-opentype")` I have also tried `format("eot")` but it didn't affect the result.

I have also tried removing the `?#iefix`, but this also shows no effect.

I have also noticed that it shows the font in the IE Debugger:
[image: Font in IE Debugger]

It just doesn't display it.

The font works fine on Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried seperating the src? I have noticed that externally served fonts always use two src attributes, one for the iefix, and the other defining the rest. Thats because IE ignores something it can't read. I'de suggest trying the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Font Family Name';
    src: url('font.eot');
    src: url('font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font.svg#fontname') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

#### Update

I have looked again at provided font files I have used in the past that work on IE (fron the League of Moveable type) and they use two src's, one with just the `eot` and no format, and then the `eot` with *iefix* and the others, like above. I hope that works.

Comment: I've just tried this now, but sadly still no effect.

Comment: @LucaTescari Sorry about that. Have you tried this solution combined with removing the format? I'm just guessing but I use fonts by `The League of Moveable Type` and just checked the included stylesheets, and thats what they do (and they work on IE). I have updated my post with a downloaded example.

Comment: I've tried it now, also with "eot" as format instead of "embedded-opentype". Both versions sadly do not work.

Comment: @LucaTescair Sorry about that (again). Have you tried with other fonts to see if the fontfile isnt broken (or considered broken) by IE?

Comment: There is an example page that came with the font on which it works. 

I've now copied the CSS form that example page into my website but this also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution.

The problem was that our webserver was blocking the ".eot" filetype. I needed to change some settings on the server and now it works just fine.